# SSMS 2016 - Mobile reports - creating custom control

Tags: reporting-services, report, custom-controls, powerbi, ssms-2016

Is it possible to create **Custom (own) controls** for the SQL Server Mobile Report publisher? Meaning own graphes (`Gauges`), styles, maps, etc...

I was unable to find any information about this topic on Google (or other sites like SO). Few days back we had lectures/training with some developer (basics of Reporting) and he shortly said that it is possible, but we haven't got time to go through it.

> My expectations (as an answer) is explanation **what tool can be used** and/or **link to tutorial**.
>
> Possibly also some **information (with source) that this cannot** be created in version 2016.

Comment: Are you sure they weren't talking about custom maps? That's possible but I dont see anything about custom visuals on other controls. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4704/create-custom-maps-for-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-mobile-reports/ If someone does find out how to do this i'd be interested as the default components don't look very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short story*: **It is not possible to create custom control in Mobile Reports Publisher as of now (March 2017).** There is no support in the software itself. However Microsoft will allow store/use [Power BI reports within Reporting services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/01/17/power-bi-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services-january-2017-technical-preview-now-available/).

---

*Long story*: I've reached out the tutorial guru and discussed this further. We've found that the original statement is not true and mobile reports cannot be adjusted in a way of creating new control or modifying style sheet.

**But:** Since Mobile reports are sort of family with product called **[Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/)**, Microsoft has decided (as described in [MS Technical preview - January 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/01/17/power-bi-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services-january-2017-technical-preview-now-available/)) to support Power BI Reports on next version MS Reporting Services. And as there can be done some visualisation changes and even create new controls, most likely we will be also able to create our own control.